# Is there any way to boost the speed of pandas program for large dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

So I have a dataset of 600K rows with multiple columns from which I used a small subset to check the code first.
[image: Subset]

I wrote this code which generates new column of PMIDs which is retrieved from a online repository

```
from pandas import read_csv
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "myemail@mail.com"

sample = read_csv("rsid_subset.csv",dtype=str)
start = timer()
def retrieve_Pmids(sample):
    res = []
    if sample["Rs_ID"].startswith("rs"):
        rs_id = sample.Rs_ID
        handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=rs_id, rettype="uilist", retmode="text")
        res = Entrez.read(handle)
        ids = ""
        if res:
            ids = ",".join(str(res['IdList'])) 
            return ids
        else:
            return "."
    else:
        return "."

sample["PMIDS"] = sample.apply(retrieve_Pmids,axis=1)
```

Which gives me the desired result
[image: Result]

Now the problem I am facing is that for the dataset of only 173 rows it takes about 133seconds.
So is there any way I can make this program faster for large dataset.
So far I have tried Dask (no imporvement), tried static typing wherever possible but not much difference, and then I used Modin module but the my main Pandas version differs from the modin's pandas version.
I also tried multiprocessing by chunking the dataset but somehow its not providing any result.
Below is the code for multiprocessing I referred from somewhere
Problem is I cant see the result, the script is getting executed but I cant see the result.

```
from Bio import Entrez
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd

SAMPLE = "D:\\Trial\\rsid_subset.csv"
CHUNKSIZE = int(20)
Entrez.email = "myemail@mail.com"
def retrieve_Pmids(sample):
    res = []
    if sample["Rs_ID"].startswith("rs"):
        rs_id = sample.Rs_ID
        handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=rs_id, rettype="uilist", retmode="text")
        res = Entrez.read(handle)
        ids = ""
        if res:
            ids = ",".join(res['IdList'])
            return ids
        else:
            return "."
    else:
        return "."
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader = pd.read_csv(SAMPLE, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
    pool = mp.Pool(4) # use 4 processes
    funclist = []
    for df in reader:
        f = pool.apply_async(retrieve_Pmids,[df])
        funclist.append(f)
```

So is there any way I can speed up the process for large dataset as I would work on such large dataset in future.

**Can anyone help me improve the above multiprocessing code in order to get the desired dataframe result?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Almost certainly, it is I/O bound with `Entrez.esearch`.... This program doesn't really use `pandas` at all.

Comment: if you working on csv then i will suggest use modin

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentioned, you could try speeding this up with either asyncio or threading. Either of them could greatly increase the speed of the io operation in Entrez.esearch.

Comment: "I also tried multiprocessing by chunking the dataset but somehow its not providing any result." what? this process should be amenable to multiprocessing.

Comment: @ravishankar chavare I installed but the pandas version in modin is lower than the version I use.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added the code for multiprocessing in the question. But the thing is its not executing the function.

Comment: @NikhilPanchal why do you think it isn't executing the function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added a print command to check whats happening and after running the script the print command wasn't executed.